# What is the adjective that says a big brother lets his little brother win against him and often give more food to his brother than to himself?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

A big brother lets his little brother win against him and often give more food to his brother than to himself.

The brother is willing to give up his stuff and give it to his little brother. He won't do that to people that are not his little brothers.

I know that in Western countries, everyone is equal. A big brother plays a game with his little brother the big brother will do his best to win against his little brother.

But in the East, sometimes the relationship is more important than "win or lose". So, in the East, the big brother just let the little brother win. I don't know why, but that is how the culture works.

I am not sure it is more natural to say "**The big brother gave up/ sacrifices his cake to his little brother for good**"?

Comment: What's the word in your language? How do dictionaries translate it to English? Why are those translations unsatisfying?

Comment: I think the idea that "Western big brothers" give no quarter when competing against their younger male siblings (whereas people from "Eastern" societies routinely let the younger sibling win) is an appallingly inaccurate and potentially insulting stereotype. But this kind of "non-competitive pseudo-play" is often called ***indulgence*** (which stretches to the sense of ***mollycoddling***).

Comment: @gotube, the translation in the dictionaries are not correct at all and I couldn't find any words that is close to what I am looking for. For example, one of the dictionaries says "The big brother conceded the cake to the little brother"